# Office Addin with React won't launch

Tags: reactjs, webpack, office365, yeoman-generator

I am trying to create an excel addin using React Fabric. I would like to use typescript in it. I used the tools create-react-app and yo, and enabled the use of TypeScript. When I trigger npm start, I get the following errors in all the tsx files.

ERROR in ./src/components/progress.tsx
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at makeIdentitySourceMap (E:\toolbar\yo-addin\node_modules\react-hot-loader\makeIdentitySourceMap.js:9:11)
    at Object.module.exports (E:\toolbar\yo-addin\node_modules\react-hot-loader\index.js:91:11)
 @ ./src/main.tsx 8:17-49
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?https://localhost:3100 webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./main.tsx

ERROR in ./src/components/app.tsx
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at makeIdentitySourceMap (E:\toolbar\yo-addin\node_modules\react-hot-loader\makeIdentitySourceMap.js:9:11)
    at Object.module.exports (E:\toolbar\yo-addin\node_modules\react-hot-loader\index.js:91:11)
 @ ./src/main.tsx 7:12-39
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?https://localhost:3100 webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./main.tsx

I see "Cannot GET /" on the browser. On Chrome's console I read "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-aDF0S1KtOesRBAL1RZ+4udo7TvBPG3BaH1xB81dOuWk='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I did not encounter any error while creatting the app.

Thanks!

Comment: what fabricjs are you referring to?

Comment: Fabric React for Office Addin!

Comment: So i ll remove the fabricjs tag, since fabricjs is something else www.fabricjs.com